# Using a view model and calling OnAppearing in ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using view models for my `ContentPage`'s in my Xamarin Forms 5 app and typically call an `Init()` method in my view model from the `OnAppearing()` method in code behind.

I tried the same approach in my `ContentView` but it's never hitting the `OnAppearing()` method.

This is my `ContentView` code:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyApp.MyContentView">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark }"
            HeightRequest="200">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding User.FullName}"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="Medium"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The view model for this content view looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    User user;
    public MyViewModel()
    {
    }

    public User User
    {
        get => user;
        set
        {
            if (user == value)
                return;

            user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        // Get user info
        var data = await _dbService.GetUser();
        if(data != null)
        {
            User = data;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(User));
        }
    }
}
```

And in my code behind, this is what I'm doing:

```
public partial class MyContentView : ContentView
{
    MyViewModel _vm;
    public MyContentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = _vm;
    }

    protected virtual void OnAppearing()
    {
        _vm.Init();
    }
}
```

This pattern is working nicely in my content pages but not working in a content view. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done and it seems to be working fine.

First, I created a `ContentView` to display the flyout header which includes user's avatar and name. Notice that I set the view model for this content view in the XAML file -- see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.FlyoutHeader">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <vm:AppViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark }"
            HeightRequest="200">
            <xct:AvatarView
                Source="{Binding UserInfo.AvatarUrl}"
                Size="100"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding UserInfo.FullName}"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="Medium"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I then created a view model named `AppViewModel` that I intend to use in multiple places, including the `FlyoutHeader.xaml` that I shared above. Here's what `AppViewModel` looks like:

```
public class AppViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   User user { get; set; }
   public AppViewModel()
   {

   }

   public User UserInfo
   {
       get => user;
       set
       {
           if (user == value)
               return;

           user = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public async void Init()
   {
       if(user == null || user.Id == Guid.Empty)
       {
           var data = await _dbService.GetUser();
           if(data != null)
           {
               UserInfo = data;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Finally, in the code behind for `FlyoutHeader.xaml.cs`, I call the `Init()` method of the view model in the constructor:

```
public partial class FlyoutHeader : ContentView
{
     AppViewModel _vm;
     public FlyoutHeader()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         _vm = new AppViewModel();
         _vm.Init();

         BindingContext = _vm;
     }
}
```

I'm actually a bit concerned that there maybe tight coupling with the UI and the `async` call being initiated in the constructor may tie up the UI thread and delay it. Please let me know if there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The content view doesn't have the lifecycle methods like the content page. So when the content view shows or displays on the screen, the OnAppearing() and OnDisAppearing method developer custom will not invoke.

So you can call the the page's OnAppearing() method to do that if there is only a content view in your page. And if there is not only one contentview, you can call the  `_vm.Init();` method when you use the instance of the content view.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. I'm trying to use this `ContentView` as my `FlyoutHeaderTemplate` and display the authenticated user's name. I ran into two issues: 1. I'm not quite clear how I'm calling the parent page's `OnAppearing()` method 2. This issue is more troubling! I created an `OnAppearing()` method in `AppShell.xaml.cs` and put a break point but I never hit it. I maybe approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: In the Shell App, just the shellcontent which is a forms page has the OnAppearing method. In addition, the data of the `AppShell.xaml` should be loaded when the app starts. So I suggest you to call the`_vm.Init();` method in the construction method the `AppShell.cs` or in the construction method of the `ContentView.cs`.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?@Sam

Comment: Just posted what I did to handle this scenario as an answer. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.